# Is it possible to use a ternary operator in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have condition like this:

```
$scope.toggleSlider = function() {
  $('.sliderButton').css('left','0') ?
     $('.sliderButton').css('left', '173px')
   : $('.sliderButton').css('left', '0')
}
```

Whenever I hit `toggleSlider` method that ternary condition should perform. Is this correct?

Comment: can you please tell me the reason to downvote my question?

Comment: Have you tried it ? Does it work ? If yes, delete the question - If no, add the error in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
$scope.toggleSlider = function() {
  $('.sliderButton').css('left', $('.sliderButton').css('left') === '0' ? '173px' : '0');
}
```

Comment: @krish what are you talking about?

Comment: I have tried your answer,when I hit `toggleSlider` method for first time css is changed from `left:173px` to `left:0px` and Icon position is changed correctly. When I click next time css should be changed from  `left:0px` to `left:173px` right? but its not getting changed.

Comment: got the solution.

Comment: small change in your answer `$('.sliderButton').css('left', $('.sliderButton').css('left') === '0px' ? '173px' : '0');`

Answer (score 3):

(this post addressees the question being asked in the title, not the actual code in the question)

In some cases<sup>1</sup> in the modern day web, you can mimic a ternary operator in pure CSS by using an extra CSS variable. For example:

```
left: calc(
  0px * var(--myVariable)
  + 173px * (1 - var(--myVariable))
);
```

Then make sure `--myVariable` is either `1` (if you want the first addend to be used) or `0` (if you want the second addend to be used).

This is particularly useful if you have a complicated calculation or if you want to avoid changing the CSS property value itself.

<sup>1</sup>: This approach only works in cases where you're doing calculations *or* toggle between a value and `initial`. It can't arbitrarily toggle between two values (like `red` and `blue`). More general toggling may be possible at some point in the future if CSS implements toggles or `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there but you should get the value and check instead of setting

```
$('.sliderButton').css('left') == '0px' ?$('.sliderButton' . ........
```

Note : Whatever you added in the css, you get it back. For ex: you may get `auto` if your css says auto.

Comment: `  $('.sliderButton').css('left')==0?$('.sliderButton').css('left')=173:$('.sliderButton').css('left')=0` Is this correct?

Comment: @krish yes it is. Try it.

Comment: should I add `px`?

Comment: @krish Whatever you added in the css, you get it back.  look here https://jsfiddle.net/mz5HC/154/

Comment: Hi.I did like this `var sb=$('.sliderButton').css('left');   sb=0?sb=173:sb=0` ternary operator is returning value correctly but there is no changes in css(my icon is displayed in old position only.if ternary operator returns `0` means,then `left:0;` but why icon position is not changed).

Comment: `sb` values turned to `0` but `$('.sliderButton').css('left')` values keeps old value only.why?